# Tuning Excel Web-Import

Tags: html, excel, reporting, jira

Excel geeks and software-engineers,

I am playing with the "Excel Webdata Import" to generate a pivot report of Bugs and affected Testcases. The data comes from an proprietary tool, and is a html-table. Most of Excel's HTML import works but I have some strange effects:

1) some TDs contain a DIV which is shown on mouse-over. In Excel I get multiple cells for the info in the DIV ( a bold heading, a description, a last modification date )

2) one HTML column has data that should go to two excel cells, a text and an icon.

Question: How can I either:

- postprocess the data in Excel (automatically at refresh)?
- tune the import stylesheet?

For 1) I would like to collapse the 3 excel rows to 3 cells in one row

For 2) I would like to split the cell using a regex or so.

I would like to avoid using an additional tool to have the tool-chain as short as possible.

Thanks for any hints and pointers.

**Edit: Here is an example row:**

```
<tr class="level0">
    <!-- case 1) -->
    <!-- some fancy javascript and div stuff in html. shown in browser is an icon + mouse-over-div -->
    <td>
        <a onMouseOver="Element.show('bug_35017')" onMouseOut="Element.hide('bug_35017')" href="jira/browse/35017" target="_blank"><img alt="Bug_" border="0" src="/images/bug_.gif?1348035189" /></a>
        <div id="bug_35017" style="padding: 5px; width: 40%; display: none; position: absolute; left: 30%; border: 1px solid #666; background: white; color: #000">
            <img alt="Bug_" border="0" src="/images/bug_.gif?1348035189" />
            <b style="color: #000">JIRA 35017</b>
            &nbsp;&nbsp; last modification: 2012-12-19 10:13:54<p/>
            <blockquote style="color: #000">
                "Delete account - Please review Testcase 12345" 
            </blockquote>
        </div>
    </td>

    <!-- case 2) -->
    <!-- a date and the info if the testcase was ok or not, using an icon in one TD -->
    <td>
                17:26:45 12.12.12 <img alt="Nok" src="/images/nok.gif?1348035189" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

I'd like to see this as:

```
| 35015 | 2012-12-19 10:13:54 | Delete account please review Testcase 12345 | 17:26:45 12.12.12 | Nok |
```

But I get :

```
| 35015                                       | 17:26:45 12.12.12 Nok |
| 2012-12-19 10:13:54                         |  |
| Delete account please review Testcase 12345 |  |
```

Comment: Traditional "what have you tried?") And yes, sample HTML will be highly appreciated, too.

Comment: Tried nothing. thought about macros but I am inexperienced with VBA.

Comment: shared sample HTML will be very much appreciated, since it's not clear from the context how many blocks to parse are in one file. This will be helpful in choosing approach: either try to cahnge extraction routine OR reformat incorrectly placed results.

Answer (score 1):

From the input it seems you use Jira as bug tracking. I'm also QA and use this for 90% of my projects, so my hint is the following - try **built-in Excel export**:

[image: Jira Excel Export]

First option will export only visible fields (they may be customized using Jira), 2nd will provide ALL possible fields / info related to issue. For my 4+ years QA experience I faced no cases so far where these 2 were not enough to produce ANY possible or impossible kinds of reports and statistics.

One more advice - add [jira](/questions/tagged/jira) tag to your question, thus you'll more likely receive relevant answers.

Comment: thanks for the input. Yes I am thinking about using this approach for JIRA also, but this particular report links jira issues to our home-brewn web-app for managing test-specs and executions. The HTML-report comes from that application and links affected TCs against JIRA-bugs in a n:m relation. (our JIRA issues have a custom field for affected TC, these are the IDs in the other application) Vote-up, but no accept as it does not answer the question.

Comment: @Bastl I see now. Could you please provide / modify your input specifying exact values from the sample HTML you'd like to obtain, and place them the way you want to see in Excel? There are many similar fields in HTML, and without context I'm a bit lost. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Bastl and yes, got my upvote - question looks much more exciting now)

Comment: @Bastl Assuming `35015` is a typo it's much more clear now. Thinking about approach)